# iphone - Adding new entity to core data model?

Tags: iphone, core-data, mapping-model, core-data-migration

Is **adding a new entity** on the new version of my core data model going to crash the apps using the older versions of core data model?

What if this entity has a relationship with an existing entity.

```
oldEntity (1)------------->(oo) newEntity
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a simple case for versioning, which can be done quite simply in a lot of instances. This sounds like one of them.

Check out the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html